# Vb.Net Checkbox to enable and disable click trough form

Tags: vb.net, forms, click

I basically have a form with a picture box filling the whole form using this as topmost overlay for games.
So what I want to do is add a Checkbox that lets me 1. click trough the form and 2. disable the click trough form.

I know how to do the click trough form part but I don't know how to connect it to a checkbox.
Also if the clicktrough form is active I can't disable or enable checkboxes anymore because of that.
Is it possible to fix that too somehow?

Code:

```
Private Const WS_EX_TRANSPARENT As Integer = &H20

Protected Overrides ReadOnly Property CreateParams() As System.Windows.Forms.CreateParams
    Get
        Dim cp As CreateParams = MyBase.CreateParams
        cp.ExStyle = cp.ExStyle Or WS_EX_TRANSPARENT
        Return cp
    End Get
End Property
```

Comment: An other way : you can use a NotifyIcon to display an icon in the ... Windows's notifications icons area with a context menu strip.

Comment: thats a great Idea to disable enable it thank you. now I just need to know how I can disable the clicktrough again.

Comment: Set a condition in CreateParams that adds  `WS_EX_TRANSPARENT` to the style when the condition is met and just call `Me.RecreateHandle()` when you want to reset it.

Comment: Thanks I got it working.

Answer (score 2):

I have an old project with a clic trough feature, there is the code :

> In a module

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Module Module1

    Public m_InitialStyle As Integer

    Public Enum GWL As Integer
        ExStyle = -20
    End Enum

    Public Enum WS_EX As Integer
        Transparent = &H20
        Layered = &H80000
    End Enum


    <DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint:="SetWindowLong")>
    Public Function SetWindowLong(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal nIndex As GWL, ByVal dsNewLong As WS_EX) As Integer
    End Function


End Module
```

> When your form is loaded :

```
m_InitialStyle = GetWindowLong(Me.Handle, GWL.ExStyle)
```

> How to use it :

```
    Private Sub VisibleToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles VisibleToolStripMenuItem.Click
        SetWindowLong(Me.Handle, GWL.ExStyle, m_InitialStyle Or WS_EX.Layered Or WS_EX.Transparent)
    End Sub

    Private Sub NormalToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles NormalToolStripMenuItem.Click
        SetWindowLong(Me.Handle, GWL.ExStyle, m_InitialStyle Or WS_EX.Layered)
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it working with the NotifyIcon thanks to @UserNam3 for that Idea.
Also thanks to @Jimi for the Me.RecreateHandle()

Final Code:

```
Dim clicktrough As Boolean = False

Private Sub DisableToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DisableToolStripMenuItem.Click
    clicktrough = False
    Me.RecreateHandle()
End Sub

Private Sub VisibleToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles VisibleToolStripMenuItem.Click
    clicktrough = True
    Me.RecreateHandle()
End Sub

Private Const WS_EX_TRANSPARENT As Integer = &H20

Protected Overrides ReadOnly Property CreateParams() As System.Windows.Forms.CreateParams
    Get
        Dim cp As CreateParams = MyBase.CreateParams
        If clicktrough = True Then
            cp.ExStyle = cp.ExStyle Or WS_EX_TRANSPARENT
        End If
        Return cp
    End Get
End Property
```